# rospy sensor_msgs.msg.BatteryState is not found

Tags: ros, rospy, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some reason I'm not able to import the BatteryState message with rospy. This is the only message I've encountered that seems to be missing. http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/BatteryState.html

I'm using ros-indigo. Anyone else have this problem?

```
zac@nuc-2:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu
>>> from sensor_msgs.msg import BatteryState
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name BatteryState
>>>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231771/rospy-sensor_msgs.msg.batterystate-is-not-found/) by [zacwitte](https://answers.ros.org/users/26086/zacwitte/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2016-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The BatteryState message was added to Indigo in the most recent release of sensor_msgs, and it has not yet reached the public apt repository.

If you really need the battery message, you can use sensor_msgs from source, or you can keep an eye on the ros-users mailing list for the announcement of the next sync, which will be made when the updated version of the package reaches the public apt repo.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zacwitte](https://answers.ros.org/users/26086/zacwitte/) on 2016-04-13**:
How might I install sensor_msgs for source for rospy?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-14**:
Have a look at the answer here: http://answers.ros.org/question/208963/installing-package-from-source-in-indigo/ , but replace the git URL for descartes with the git URL provided on the sensor_msgs wiki page.

**Comment by [zacwitte](https://answers.ros.org/users/26086/zacwitte/) on 2016-04-14**:
Thanks. I actually ended up installing BatteryState as a custom message in my package, copy/pasted from github.